# Search algorithms in games?

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm currently writing on my bachelor work about "Search algorithms in computer games", but I'm having problems to find resources in which game which algorithm was used.

I try to find games who use one of the following algorithms:
Djikstra
A*
BSP-Trees
K-D Trees

Does anyone of you know a good homepage where I can look thinks like this up?
(I found some stuff myself, but I would appreciate it if someone could provide me some more info)

Comment: This might be more suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Those are path finding searches. Are you interested in minimax search as well? If you name an algorithm, there is probably a game that uses it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For AI pathfinding algorithms, some game companies use [Autodesk Kynapse](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=14853522).

Games that utilize the Unreal Engine have access to [Binary Space Partitioning Trees](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy%3aBSP_Tree).

Comment: Or pick Doom. 2D BSP is easier ;-)

Comment: Do you have a link where it says something about doom and that it is using bsp?

Comment: @blawa - BSP is used heavily in first person games, but the BSP portion of the original Doom engine is known because the source code was open sourced. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_engine

Answer (score 0):

Start at [List of Open Source Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_games) or [Open Source Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_games).  As they are all open source, you can find examples of the algorithms in use.

Comment: Ty for your answers. The thing is just that I need proof of which game uses which of the algorithms I'm writing about